# How to travel long distance in global map

Tags: ros, local-costmap, global-costmap, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to move use move_base to travel distances in the vicinity of 35m.  Increasing the size of the local window so that it is large enough causes the update rate of the cost map to fall too low.  I would like to keep a reasonable local costmap window (e.g., 6m x 6m) but still be able to set a larger global goal.  Is this possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234099/how-to-travel-long-distance-in-global-map/) by [mitch](https://answers.ros.org/users/22960/mitch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes; just use a larger global map. The local and global map sizes do not need to match.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mitch](https://answers.ros.org/users/22960/mitch/) on 2016-05-10**:
Where do I set the size of the global map?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-05-11**:
If you map is stored in an image format (like the maps from gmapping), the total map size is determined by the image dimensions, and you can change the map size by changing the size of the image. (for other maps you'll have to check their documentation).